# How do I use StaticRoute values in Hamlet?

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

The TH call

```
$(staticFiles "static")
```

dumps a load of values of type `StaticRoute`.

Hamlet typesafe URLs (i.e. `@{...}`) take values of type `Route Foo`, where `Foo` is my foundation.

There must be a way of using the `StaticRoute` values as URLs in Hamlet.  That is, one of the following must exist:

- A standard function of type `StaticRoute -> Route Foo`
- A different way of embedding `StaticRoute` values in Hamlet

However, I can't find either.  Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `StaticR` constructor, which will convert a route for the static subsite to a route for your specific application. Technically, you can name that constructor whatever you want, but the scaffolding site and just about every example and real application I've ever seen stick with that convention.